# Better way to see java error stacktrace

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing a Java Spring boot application using Eclipse. Whenever I got a runtime exception, the terminal or console display tons of lines for the stack trace.

It is difficult to skip all these lines to spot the cause of the error. My question is how to browse/navigate that stacktrace in an organized way. Maybe organizing them in an expandable tree or something else.

Any idea/plugin/tool that could help.

Comment: catch the exception or implement loggers!

Comment: Don't mess with the stack trace.  Log it and look at all the output.

Comment: A stack trace is just a linear list, there is no tree structure.